# Trying to concatenate input box and bind value in it

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to concatenate input box and bind value in it
 I just put a asp label inside  column so that I can bind value below it

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-size:large"><b>Standard Sizes & Tolerances</b></td><td>                   
         <asp:Label  id="lblStdSize_Toler" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>                    
    </td>
</tr>
```

C# side I assigned a table to label:

```
lblStdSize_Toler.Text = "<table ><thead><tr><th>Size Range Min(mm)</th><th>Size Range Max (mm)</th><th>Tolerance, mm (-)</th><th>Tolerance, mm (+) mm</th></tr></thead>";
lblStdSize_Toler.Text = lblStdSize_Toler.Text+ "<tr>";

lblStdSize_Toler.Text = lblStdSize_Toler.Text + "<td>" + tdc_property + "</td>";
```

I am getting value in a label, how can I get this value in input I am trying like this:

```
lblStdSize_Toler.Text = lblStdSize_Toler.Text+ "<td><input>" + tdc_property + "</input></td>";
```

But I am getting value beside input box not inside input box . How to get value inside input box

Comment: Why not work with actual aspnet webform controls instead of building your own `table` and `input` as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOU need to use `value` like below:-

```
lblStdSize_Toler.Text = lblStdSize_Toler.Text+ "<td><input value='"+ tdc_property +"'></td>";
```

Note:-`</input>` is incorrect.